# std::lock() equivalent for boost::shared_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have a numbers of objects, each associated with a boost::shared_mutex (I need the shared/unique lock capability).

In some occasion in the code I need to obtain unique ownership of multiple objects at once.

```
for (FileMetaData* entry : smd->fileSet) {
    entry->fileMutex.lock();
}

// some critical work

for (FileMetaData* entry : smd->fileSet) {
    entry->fileMutex.unlock();
}
```

Doing something like this results in deadlock when different threads try to obtain different sets of locks.

I found that std::lock () suits my use-case. But is there an equivalence for boost::shared_mutex?

Edit:

Regarding the ordered locking pattern, it doesn't work exactly for my case:

```
T1 lock (C,D,E)
T2 wants to lock (B,D), but can only obtain the lock for B
T1 spawns T3 which works on (B,C), it stuck when obtaining the lock for B
```

So the problem is that an extra lock on B is required when T1 spawns T3, this breaks the ordered locking pattern. I think this problem can be solved if T2 doesn't hold the lock for B when D is not lockable, essentially what std::lock does.

Comment: If you know which locks you need all at once -- i.e. you have the entire set in hand before you start locking -- just sort the locks using any criterion whatsoever and lock them in that order. As long as all threads respect the same lock ordering, they can never deadlock. (This is sometimes called the "ordered locking pattern".)

Comment: @Nemo:  Here is a performance comparison of various multi-lock algorithms, including the sorted algorithm:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::lock` (or equivalently `boost::lock`, collectively "the lock functions") to perform shared ownership locking as well as exclusive locking, depending on what you pass in to be locked - anything `Lockable` will work. For example, if you have want to lock two `std::mutex`/`boost::mutex`s `A, B` and `boost::shared_mutex SM` in exclusive mode, you simply pass the three to `std::lock`:

```
std::lock(A, B, SM);
```

if you instead want to lock `SM` in shared ownership mode, you can create an unlocked `boost::shared_lock` for it and pass *that* into the locking functions:

```
boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> bsl{SM, boost::defer_lock};
std::lock(A, B, bsl);
```

On a note unrelated to your question - style preference - I prefer to always construct RAII locks to pass into `std::lock` so I can't screw up unlocking, so I'd actually write:

```
auto alk = boost::make_unique_lock(A, std::defer_lock);
auto blk = boost::make_unique_lock(B, std::defer_lock);
// boost::make_shared_lock(), where are you?!?
boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> bsl{SM, boost::defer_lock};
std::lock(alk, blk, bsl);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. In my sample code, you can see that each mutex is stored in a FileMetaData struct, which has a pointer residing in a fileSet. How should I extract these mutexes to become arguments for std::lock?

Comment: Other than what Casey posts, note that C++14 already includes std::shared_mutex and std::shared_lock, which is almost same to boost. Clang/Gcc already implemented that。

Comment: @jeremy if you know the number of mutexes at compile time you can do a number of different template tricks. Where you build up a constexpr object and pass it as the arguments to a std::lock.
If the number of mutexes is runtime boost lock alone accept a pair of iterators to say a vector<mutex&> or vector<mutex*>
Read this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21106127/1943599