# Calling std::lock () with std::vector <mutex*>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to replace the following code with `std::lock()`:

```
for (mutex* m : mutexes) {
   m->lock();
}
```

Is there anyway I could invoke `std::lock ()` on those mutexes given a `std::vector<mutex*>`?

Comment: If you need to lock every element in the vector, couldn't you simply keep a single mutex controlling access to the entire vector? Then you could use `std::lock()`

Comment: @mebob That doesn't necessarily preserve the same semantics. Imagine the `vector` contains a dozen mutexes, each of which provides mutual exclusion while accessing a dozen different objects respectively. But there is one section of code where you need to lock out access to all of these objects simultaneously. That's where you'd need the above `std::lock()` call. Now, if you were to replace those dozen mutexes with a single one, you'd need to lock access to *all* the objects when accessing *any* of them, rather doing it in just once section in the previous scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the standard library doesn't provide an overload for [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) that takes a pair of iterators pointing to lockable objects. To use `std::lock` you must know the number of lockable objects at compile time, and pass them as arguments to the function. However, Boost does provide an [overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_range) that takes iterators, and it'll work with `std::mutex`.

The other piece of scaffolding you'll need is [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html); this will apply an extra dereference when you dereference the iterator (needed because you have `std::vector<std::mutex*>` and not `std::vector<std::mutex>`. The latter would not be very useful anyway since `std::mutex` cannot be copied or moved.)

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/indirect_iterator.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    using mutex_list = std::vector<std::mutex*>;
    mutex_list mutexes;

    boost::indirect_iterator<mutex_list::iterator> first(mutexes.begin()), 
                                                   last(mutexes.end());
    boost::lock(first, last);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5935159cd15349ea)